# Abandoned webform log

Tags: rules, webforms, cron

I'm building a huge form with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module and need advice for a way to save not fully submitted forms even without **Showing** "`Save draft`" **button** options is enabled and button is visible (which is another PITA).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a custom module that calls an AJAX function after each field of the Webform has been changed that fires the same function that the Save draft button does.

Shouldn't be too complicated, there is a starting point at [Use AJAX to auto save a draft](https://www.drupal.org/node/1319926) which should hopefully push you in the right direction, plus [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) might also help